# Google analytics PHP API returns empty values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I perform an API request to google analytics I often get no data back. Sometimes it works and other times it just doesnt.

My API call looks like this:

```
public function get_pageviews( )
    {
        $result = $this->service->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $this->profile_id,                                      // report id
            $this->convert_time( "-".$this->timespan." days", "Y-m-d" ),    // start date
            $this->convert_time( $this->end, "Y-m-d" ),                     // end date
            "ga:pageviews",                                                 // metrics
            array( "dimensions" => "ga:date" )                              // other...
        );
        return $result;
    }
```

The correct output is:

```
 ["totalsForAllResults"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ga:pageviews"]=>
    string(4) "1503"
  }
  ["rows"]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120823"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "333"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120824"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "185"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120825"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "52"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120826"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "110"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120827"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "335"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120828"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "222"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120829"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "257"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120830"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "9"
    }
  }
```

And the wrong output, with no data is:

```
["totalsForAllResults"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ga:pageviews"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["rows"]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120823"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120824"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120825"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120826"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120827"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120828"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120829"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "20120830"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the multidimensional array **rows** is not empty but the values in the array are set to 0 while it is the exact same request i have sent using the Google Analtyics API.

Is there anything I am missing in my request or something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you send too many requests at a time.

Comment: This would be very bizar. Only previous request is the login request. No simultaneous requests are send at that time and there is a timelapse of several seconds between both requests that get me a different output.